# HaveGooglePlayServices and OnConnected

Tags: java, android

I am currently attempting to work with accessing GooglePlayServices.

I have recently found out another way of accessing GooglePlay Services, this time through OAuth 2.0. I have also found an example from the gitHub displaying an example on how to use it.

https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/blob/master/tasks-android-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/tasks/android/TasksSample.java

However, I have been a little confused with the new method, specifically where to start sending requests.

I am attempting to use Google Play Client to access a person's location, and I'm not sure where to put the start of the locationRequest. When using the GoogleAPIClient, the start was in onConnected.

However, there is nothing in this specific example I have found, to be close to this. The closest was:

```
  private void haveGooglePlayServices() {
    if (credential.getSelectedAccountName() == null) {
      chooseAccount();
    } else {
      // This is where I think I need to start sending requests.
      AsyncLoadTasks.run(this);
    }
  }
```

(The snippet is line 197 to 206)

**Is this assumption right, or is there some other place I am required to start sending location requests?**

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in

```
onConnected(Bundle connectionhint)
```

like that

```
 @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        mLatitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
        mLongitudeText.setText(String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
    }
}
```

or check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html)